# flutter go_router How to remove other routes in the routing line?

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router

My current routing line is A -> B -> C -> D
now, I am on page D , i want to remove B .
What should I do?
I searched in the issue and found no answer

Answer (score -1):

In go_Router, you can use GoRouter.of(context).go(newRoute); to remove all old paths

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: OP wants to remove a single route, not all the old routes.